# Why are these UPDATE & INSERT INTO queries not working? PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 queries. Query #1 updates some things in the database, and Query #2 inserts some data into the table.

Code:

```
function add_like($id) {

    $connection = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

    $id = $connection->real_escape_string($id);

    $query = $connection->query("UPDATE `posts` SET `post_likes` = `post_likes` + 1 WHERE `id` = '$id'");
    $likes_query = $connection->query("INSERT INTO `likes` VALUES (".$_SESSION['user_login'].", $id)");
}
```

The first query (`$query`) should add 1 like to the database. So starting at 0 it should +1. Instead, it does +12.

The second query (`$likes_query`) does not `INSERT INTO likes`.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

---

**UPDATE:**

Changed the second query to:

```
$likes_query = $connection->query("INSERT INTO `likes` (`user_id`, `post_id`) VALUES ('$user', '$id')");
```

Comment: Are you sure the function is only invoked once?  Is there an error from the database on the second query?  (It doesn't look like you're *checking* for errors.  You really should.)  Maybe the first inserted value in the second query needs to be wrapped in quotes?  Also note that you have a SQL injection vulnerability in that query.  You should look into using prepared statements instead.  http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: @David The function was indeed ran multiple times through a while loop. As for the second query, I have the displaying of errors enabled but am not seeing any at the moment.

Comment: Are you sure you're *correctly* getting errors from the database?  Again, the code shown doesn't indicate this.  And given that SQL injection vulnerability, that second query could be doing *anything* really.

Comment: Don't use `insert` without listing the columns.  You might want to use a trigger to maintain the consistency between the two tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I changed the code a little bit (see original post). Now it inserts the `$id` into the DB but not the `$user`. It says it's undefined while I actually defined it at the top of the page? ---- EDIT: fixed it by defining it inside the function. (Quite new to this ^_^) Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

**Final code:**

```
function add_like($id) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_login'])) {
        $user = $_SESSION["user_login"];
    }
    else {
        $user = "";
    }

    $connection = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

    $id = $connection->real_escape_string($id);

    $query = $connection->query("UPDATE `posts` SET `post_likes` = `post_likes` + 1 WHERE `id` = '$id'");
    $likes_query = $connection->query("INSERT INTO `likes` (`user_id`, `post_id`) VALUES ('$user', '$id')");
}
```

All issues fixed. Thanks for all your comments!

Comment: ... your code will break if a user has " or ' in the name. even worse, if users can chose their own names (as is normal), you're vulnerable to SQL injection! you really should escape $user ..

Comment: @hanshenrik I got that covered. At registration I used strip_tags() to delete all of those characters from everything they typed.

Comment: its usually called escape_string (mysql, mysqli), or quote (PDO), thus 
    $query = $connection->query("UPDATE `posts` SET `post_likes` = `post_likes` + 1 WHERE `id` = '".$connection->escape_string($id)."'";

    $likes_query = $connection->query("INSERT INTO `likes` (`user_id`, `post_id`) VALUES ('".$connection->escape_string($user)."', '$id');

Comment: if you use strip_tags, special-character usernames will be corrupted, special characters will be lost etc, when you add it to your database!

Comment: sure sometimes its not important, but striptags is _GENERALLY_ the wrong way to do it. you really should learn how to insert data into databases, safely, escaped, without corruption :p